# Axios "catch" is not executing on 403 response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Returning a 403 response from a node/express app. The browser network inspector works as expected, but axios "catch" does not execute.
Axios "then" is executing and with a undefined response.

If I return 200 instead of 403, the response object doesn't get undefined value.

Thoughts ?

Middleware:

```
function authorize(permissions) {
    return async function (req, res, next) {
        if (await req.user.can(permissions)){
            return next();
        }

        return res.status(403).json({message: 'Not enough permissions', permissionsRequired: permissions});
    };
}
```

Route:

```
router.get('/', authorize('read_user'), async (req, res) => {
    return await simplePaginateModelJson(req, res);
});
```

Client side:

```
const getData = (searchFields = {}, page = 1) => {
    simplePaginateList(props.modelName, searchFields,{page: page, limit: props.itemsCountPerPage}).then(r => {
      console.log('res', r);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('err', err);
    });
  }
```

Network:

[image]

Console:

[image]

Comment: Where’s the actual `axios` call? Show what’s happening inside `simplePaginationList`.

Comment: Your `authorize()` function looks potentially dangerous.  If `req.user.can(permissions)` rejects your request will hang (never return a response of any kind).  Your middleware `async` function will reject and Express is not paying any attention to that returned promise so `next()` never gets called, your main request handler is never called and a response never gets sent.